# How can I insert my mathematical formula?

Tags: matlab, math, formula, calculator, mach

[image: equation]

I need to write above equation to my Matlab code but while writing it I got confused. `M0=1.695`, `tetha1=41.31 degree`, and `gamma=1.4`.

When I insert those numbers the result is `M1=2.5476`, but it should be around 1.51. Would you please write that code in Matlab?

I will insert my code also;

```
M1 = sqrt((2.4^2*M0^4*(sind(t1)^2)-4*(M0^2*(sind(t1)^2)-1)*(1.4*M0^2*(sind(t1)^2)+1))/((2.8*M0^2*(sind(t1)^2)-2.4)*(0.4*M0^2*(sind(t1)^2)+2)));
```

Comment: This is funny, but it happens. So basically, your formula is correct but the formula gives you M1^2 not M1.

Comment: But I used sqrt at the beginning. How it can give me the M1^2 ?

Comment: You are confusing something. For your given values 2.5476 is correct answer. I wrote the function and I am getting the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote you function in Matlab and for your given values (gamma=1.4, M0=1.695, tetha1=41.31) I am getting the same values. Here's the code:

```
function y = m1(g, M0, t1) % Do not edit this line.

  numarator = ((g+1)^2)*(M0^4)*(sind(t1)^2) - 4*((M0^2)*(sind(t1)^2)-1)*(g*(M0^2)*(sind(t1)^2)+1)
  denominator = (2*g*(M0^2)*(sind(t1)^2)-(g+1))*((g-1)*(M0^2)*(sind(t1)^2)+2)
  y = sqrt(numarator/denominator)

end % Do not edit this line.
```

Calling the function with given values:

```
m1(1.4, 1.695, 41.31)
```

gives:

```
numarator =

   17.9440


denominator =

    2.7648


y =

    2.5476


ans =

    2.5476
```

Comment: @ahmet if it answers your question accept the answer so that others do not bother, unless they have a different approach.